# Is there a way of creating more than 3 inlined fields in a discord.js embeded message?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create an embed for a discord bot using node.js. I want the embed to have 4 inlined fields so that there effectively are 4 columns with and an arbitrary number of rows in each column. When i use the following code:

```
var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .addFields(
        { name: "col1", value: 'test1', inline: true},
        { name: "col2", value: 'test2', inline: true},
        { name: "col3", value: 'test3', inline: true},
        { name: "col4", value: 'test4', inline: true},
    )
```

it outputs this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMqGB.png)

As you can see, the fourth column is automatically put in another line instead of in another column. So my question is: is it possible to avoid this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly this is not possible, embeds are not easy to work with and often you won't be able to get the result you are seeking.

Comment: @CastorMann If you think my answer was satisfactory you should mark it as correct.

Comment: oh, how do I do that? I'm new here. I upvoted the answer but apparently I don't have enough reputation for it to be publicly recorded.

Comment: @CastorMann You click the check mark under the vote buttons

Answer (score 0):

Currently embeds can't have more then 3 fields inline and afaik discord dont plan to increase the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Embeds are rendered client-side, so the maximum number of columns can be even lower than 3 depending on the field size. I'm working on a bot and when I check the embeds from my phone, it will only render one column at a time even if it enough screen size.